# How to do matching from different files with different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, set, logical-or

I have a kind of data like this:

```
course_ID subject_IDS
C242 E434\tT423\tS32
C98 F8\tW109\tU275\tV33
```

In which the number of `subject_IDS` per each `course_ID` is different (maybe one course has one and the other has more than one). And for each `subject_IDS`, has a file contains (these files should contain the same students ids) like this:

```
student_IDs\tstudent_IDs\thas_this_subject_or_not
124\t124\t2
54\t54\t1
832\t832\t2
99\t99\t1
```

In which 1 determines that this student with this `student_ID` hasn't that subject and 2 is the opposite.

I need to walk through each `subject_ID` in `course_ID` and at the end have one file determining if the student with that ID has taken any of these subjects for that course (like doing `OR` by converting `2` to `0` first and then do the `OR`; so at the end will be `0` for having any of these subjects within that one course and `1` otherwise)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pandas dataframe where you combine all files and then each row contains: `course_ID`, `subject_ID`, `student_ID` and `has_this_subject_or_not`. Then convert the `has_this_subject_or_not` column to a boolean column as you already suggested. Now you can group on `course_ID` and `student_ID`:

```py
# simplified data:
data = [[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 0]]
cols = ['course_ID', 'subject_ID', 'student_ID', 'has_this_subject_or_not']
df_combined = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df_combined.groupby(by=['course_ID', 'student_ID']).has_this_subject_or_not.sum() > 0
```

**Output**

```
course_ID  student_ID
1          1              True
2          1             False
```

Comment: I don't think what you did is right, because at the end; I want to know if `student_ID` and `has_this_subject_or_not `. Also, I couldn't combine all of them at the beginning since `subject_IDs` has a different number of columns (i.e 1st course may have subjects but 2nd has 4 subjects).

Comment: Okay that I misunderstood your question, because you state you already have the `student_ID` and `has_this_subject_or_not` relation given in a file and you want to know if for a combination of student and course each student has at least taken one of the required subjects. You can combine them by creating a dataframe for each subject file, add the subject and course columns and then concatenate all dataframes. Then, the above code should work, but correct me if I am wrong.